# CheckboxTreeViewer on checked Children node get Parent node value

Tags: eclipse-rcp, jface, treeviewer

I am using JFace CheckboxTreeViewer and adding on ICheckStateListener to get checked elemets,

My CheckboxTreeViewer  structure is as follows,

```
P1
 ----Child1
 ----Child2
 ----Child3
 ----Child4
P2
 ----Child6
 ----Child7
 ----Child8
 ----Child9
```

My Requirement is that when I am checked a Children node to get its Related parent node

for example

when I checked Child8 then get Parent Node p2 
when I checked Child2 then get Parent Node p1

how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the element that has changed from the `CheckStateChangedEvent` passed to the listener by calling the `getElement` method:

```java
public void checkStateChanged(CheckStateChangedEvent event) {

  Object changed = event.getElement();
```

This is the object that your tree content provider provided. So you can get its parent by asking the content provider:

```java
  ITreeContentProvider provider = (ITreeContentProvider)viewer.getContentProvider();

  Object parent = provider.getParent(changed);
```

where `viewer` is the `CheckboxTreeViewer`.